# Rstudio -- graphics locator() gets stuck under manipulate()

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm QC-ing a large dataset using `RStudio`. I'm viewing chunks of it using a graphics montage made using regular R graphics, with some `manipulate()` controls to control the subsetting. When I see something funny on a display, I want to pick some XY coordinate pairs (NOT data points, but in the same space), hit the `Finish` button provided by `locator()` to capture my picks, then go back to browsing. In this way I am building up a set of picked XY locations for further processing.

So my `manipulate()` controls are mostly subsetting parameters, but I also have a button called `Pick Points` to enter `locator()` mode.

This almost works, but when I hit `Finish` to terminate `locator()`, things don't quite work right. `locator()` finishes and returns a list of coordinate arrays as expected, but the graphics display stays in `locator()` crosshair mode and the `Finish` button persists. Any further clicks or `Finish` button clicks provoke an error popup `Method not found`.

I can right-mouse on the graph and `Reload` to reset things without hurting the running program or my saved data, but it's a bit distracting.

Here's a minimal example that provokes the bug.

```
demonstrateBug <- function() {
manipulate(
  {
    if( pickData ){
      locData <- locator()
      nPoint <- length( locData$x )
      message( " ... Picked ", nPoint, " points" )
    } else {
      plot( runif(10), runif(10) )
    }
  },
  pickData = button("Pick Points")
)
}
```

I've tried Google but there are very few references to the specific combination of `manipulate()` and `locator()`, and nothing about a bug like this.

`locator()` works OK from the RStudio console when run against a `manipulate()`-enhanced graphics plot, but that won't do what I want.

If I give `locator()` a fixed number of points, it returns on cue, but the cross-hairs and button still persist. I don't want a fixed number of points, anyway.

Running R 3.1.2 RStudio 0.99.441 on OSX Yosemite

*(I've never asked for help on this platform before, so I hope this all comes out right!)*

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in 0.99.441 on Fedora 20...

Comment: Probably the best thing is to file a bug report, I don't think it's an issue with your code, looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Bug now reproduced on R 3.1.2 RStudio 0.98.1091 on Windows 7. Same thing happens using `identify()`. I have submitted it to GitHub at https://github.com/rstudio/manipulate/issues/2 which I hope is OK etiquette. I don't know how to close it out here so if a sysadmin sees this please can they oblige?

Comment: Thanks to nico for reproducing the bug and Thomas Kilian for improving my Markdown. I will try to give them some stackoverflow.kudos if I can figure it out.

Comment: ... and it turns out it's known behavior, not a priority for the developers. Too bad, I'll survive.